# Aggregate values to FALSE if any of the value contains FALSE GROUP BY a column

Tags: sql, group-by, google-bigquery, aggregate

I got the following table

| FFId | PId | PDId | Emp | Operating |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 885 | 3022 | 816 | 1090A | true |
| 871 | 3022 | 816 | 1090A | false |
| 839 | 7465 | 7196 | 989A | true |
| 839 | 7465 | 7196 | 1094A | true |
| 782 | 3994 | 4290 | 1176A | true |
| 796 | 3994 | 4290 | 1176A | false |

And I would like to aggregate the Operating value into false when there are either true or false with the same PId, PDId, Emp

So the expected result would be

| FFId | PId | PDId | Emp | Operating | New Operating |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 885 | 3022 | 816 | 1090A | true | false |
| 871 | 3022 | 816 | 1090A | false | false |
| 839 | 7465 | 7196 | 989A | true | true |
| 839 | 7465 | 7196 | 1094A | true | true |
| 782 | 3994 | 4290 | 1176A | true | false |
| 796 | 3994 | 4290 | 1176A | false | false |

Could you please help me here to generate SQL query. Thanks!

Comment: So "*when there are either true or false*" evaluates to False, so just put false.

Comment: Yes, you can say so. when there are either true or false Group BY PairingDutyId

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider below (BgQuery Standard SQL)

```
select *, 
  logical_and(Operating) over(partition by PId, PDId, Emp) as New_Operating
from your_table
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]